# MobileMonkey chat is not poping in Android webview only on Android 11

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chatbot, android-browser

I am using mobilemonkey chat in my application, on clicking a button I am navigating to a webview. In Android 11 I am getting a blank white screen or sometimes monkey chat icon appears and moves back to blank white screen, but in Android 9, 10 and 12 the chat bot opens without any issue.